# Parse datetime string in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, timezone

I built a Golang server that read DateTime fields in SQL Server, it returns me this kind of date: "2020-05-28T11:14:26.227Z", but when I try to parse in TypeScript\Angular it returns me this: "28-05-2020 **13**:14:26:227" looks like it add 2 hour.

Maybe is the wrong time zone? How can I set the correct timezone?

Both Database and angular app is in my computer (same timezone)

Comment: what is the timezone in your server?

Comment: Javascript (and hence Node) don't do time zones. Try using a third party library like [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment).

Comment: posted a solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing DateTime's between a server and JavaScript is a right PITA. I wanted to ignore the timezone, and didn't feel the need for an entire library e.g. Moment so I wrote a conversion helper for Angular as follows:

Converting dates received from the server in JavaScript:

```
// Reverse the timezone offset (this might only work for timezones earlier than GMT - so test)
this.translateToClient = function (input) {
    if (!input) return null;
    let result = new Date(Date.parse(input));

    result.setMinutes(result.getMinutes() + result.getTimezoneOffset());

    return result;
};
```

Converting dates in JavaScript to send back to the server:

```
// Send back UTC time instead of timezone time.
this.translateToServer = function (input) {
    if (!input) return null;

    return new Date(Date.UTC(
        input.getFullYear()
        , input.getMonth()
        , input.getDate()
        , input.getHours()
        , input.getMinutes()
        , input.getSeconds()
        , input.getMilliseconds()
    ));
};
```

Note: Some server technologies (e.g. ASP.NET) can also automatically apply a timezone offset which also has to be configured correctly.

I found I needed to send my DateTime to the client like this:

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind(MyValue, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked fine! I actually didn't know about moment library, but your solution it's all i need